# how to select one or all value from a table using stored procedures parameters

Tags: sql-server

I have a problem when I want to select more then one value in SQL Server. I found a lot of examples with SQL Server Reporting Services but I want to use this stored procedure in a Windows form application.

I have one parameter

```
@emp nvarchar(50)

select * from table
where crdname = @emp
```

This one returns table for a single `crdname`, but I have a situation when I need the table with all `crdname`.

I have a solution using C# and 2 stored procedures, one procedure for all `crdname` and one procedure for a single `emp`, but it's a lot of code for something that I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on the scope of the requirements.  Do you want it to be one or all?  Do you want to be able to do multiple values?  For the one or all scenario:

Have a way to pass NULL to the stored procedure then change the `WHERE` to `WHERE (@emp is NULL OR crdname = @emp)`.
When the parameter is NULL, the WHERE will evaluate to true and you will get all records.  When the parameter is not NULL, you will pull the single value you are looking for.

For the multiple values scenario:
Change the `=` to `IN`.  You might have to create a string split function since you are passing in nvarchar for the parameter.

Comment: I want it to be one or all. I will try with null but i am not very sure it more better then more code in c# :) thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use the same stored procedure, but add a condition on the parameter:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.YourSP @emp INT = NULL --I assumed the data type
AS
BEGIN
     SELECT *
     FROM YourTable
     WHERE crdname = @emp 
     OR @emp IS NULL
END;
```

Then when you want all the results, then call the sp like this:

```
EXEC dbo.YourSP
```

And when you want one, then do this:

```
EXEC dbo.YourSP 1234
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine both stored procedures into one, by passing in null for `@emp`

```
select *
from table
where @emp is null or crdname = @emp
```

If @emp is null, then the first condition is true and all rows are returned.

I would suggest two stored procedures, because the above approach is a bit convoluted. But that's just me :)

If you find yourself writing alot of sp's for your winform app, then maybe an ORM would help - e.g. Entity framework?